# stretch columns / headers QTableView in pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to stretch the columns width. Here is the working code. But when I add the line with QHeaderView.ResizeToContents the MainWindow crashes.

```
        self.tabresult = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tabresult, buttontext)
        self.tabresult.layout = QGridLayout() 
        self.tabresult.setLayout(self.tabresult.layout)

        self.view_minmax = QTableView(self.tabresult)    
        self.view_minmax.resize(1200,500) 

        self.modelminmax = gui_tables.PandasModel(self.df) 
        self.view_minmax.setModel(self.modelminmax) 
        self.view_minmax.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) # <---what's WRONG here?
        self.view_minmax.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.view_minmax.sortByColumn(7, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        self.view_minmax.setWindowTitle(buttontext)
        self.view_minmax.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.view_minmax.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(209, 209, 209)"
                           "; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);")
        self.view_minmax.show()
```

like 'AmusingTeebs' answered here
[How to stretch QTableView last column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070340/how-to-stretch-qtableview-last-column-header)

I just have to add this line in, like I've done above. Everything works perfect without that line. I Just want to stretch the columns width to it contents. It also wont work with (QHeaderView.Stretch)

```
        self.view_minmax.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Can someone help me please, (sorry for asking again ^^)

Comment: change `setResizeMode` to `setSectionResizeMode`

Comment: **THANK YOU**! That was it.